# Joomla question about custom module

Tags: module, components, joomla1.5

I'm very new to Joomla. I have a question about components/modules.

I'm doing the development of a site for a firm and they provided me with custom news releases component that's supposed to show on the home page. From what I've seen, I can call modules to a page with "" based on their position.

Do I do the same sort of thing to get this component to display? Can anyone help me out please. Let me know if I'm not being clear.

EDIT: I figured out that I have to add this as a menu item, but this makes it into it's own page. I want this just as a module on the right of the home page. What do I need to do to achieve this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this is a component than you won't be able to display it in a module position. You will have to write a new module to do that or use some modules which wrap around other types of content. See [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/2723/details), maybe this plugin  will fit.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a component you can also use the Component Loader extension to load the component output in a module position.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/embed-a-include/10721